# How to add stylesheets to the style chooser?

Tags: notebooks, stylesheet

I'd like thumbnails of my own stylesheets to show up in the menu option File > New > Styled Notebook:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible? I suppose so. Whether or not you, yourself, can do it will depend how skillful you are are modifying a very complicated Mathematica palette, which is what the stylesheet chooser is. You can find it (on OS X, which appears to be the OS you are using) at `/Applications/Mathematica11.0.1.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Palettes/StylesheetChooser.nb`